# How to compare the context objects of the two different Activities..?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have a class where I am getting context objects from more than 10 activities.

I want to know the context object of which activity is at the instant.

I have tried the following but no results.

```
context.equals(One.this);

context.equeals(One.class);
```

If any one having any idea please share with me!

Comment: how do you pass context objects to the class?

Comment: I think you can use Constructor to put exactly context object that you want

Comment: put code how you are pasing and recieving conext objects.

Comment: "I have a class where I am getting context objects from more than 10 activities." -- that is an exceedingly bad idea, as you will generate memory leaks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I hope you aren't holding on to these `Context` references longer than necessary, I found out what a wonderful source of memory leaks this can be if not handled correctly!

If they are all `Activity` instances you can treat them as such and use:

```
if ( activity instanceof MyClassActivityOne ) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Hello chris, Thank you for Knowledge sharing, Can you please give the working samples for any other scenario have to use this code?

Comment: this is one is working, if we want to compare two activities and vice versa. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ten activities seems like a lot to have at once.

What are you trying to do by comparing context objects? Sometimes the answer to the question
"How do I do this?" is "Don't do this! Tell us what you want, and we'll suggest another
path to follow."